shower mixing valve has low hot water pressure
I have been having problems with my single handle shower mixing valve.  For a while, when getting the shower to a hotter setting, it would suddenly shudder and lose all hot water pressure.   I would turn it off and then slowly add back the hot, but could only get it to warm.
I then removed and replaced the cartridge.   Same issue.
I then removed the cartridge and tried to flush the mixer by turning on the service shut offs one at a time.  The cold had seemingly full pressure.  The hot was very weak.  I turned it on and off a number of times attempting to flush it, but no luck.
Is the internal part of the valve serviceable?   or does the whole mixing valve need to be replaced?



Sounds like a messed up anti-scald valve.
You don't say what the actual Kohler valve designation is to confirm/deny that.
Or it could be a problem external to the valve.

actual cartridge now shown

And that number leads nowhere for me. Closest is same number with a B instead of an A, and that does not mention any Kohler valves; but of course it's not quite the same number. But the number shown is getting no results when I look.
